# Cloudera data science workbench displaying different time

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

We have CDSW up and running with all the basic configurations in non-prod same as in Prod. But we are observing that it is showing time difference of 5hrs assuming it is in UTC.

For example: when I type the command print(datetime.now()), it shows me 16:30 when the actual time is 11:30 am. Is there any parameter that I need to set for CDSW in Cloudera manager to display the correct time? I have looked for many but I didn't find good documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [the documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/latest/topics/cdsw_engine_configuration.html#engine_environment__time_zones) the default timezone for CDSW is UTC, regardless of the time on the master node.

However this can be overruled, by setting the timezone manually. I suspect that this has been done on one of the nodes. If you want constency, consider doing this on the other node as well.

Here is the relevant bit of the documentation:

> To change to your preferred time zone, for example, Pacific Standard
>   Time (PST), navigate to **Admin** > **Engines**. Under the **Environmental
>   Variables section**, add a new variable with the name set to `TZ` and
>   value set to `America/Los_Angeles`, and click **Add**.

Note that these steps should be within the Cloudera Data Science Workbench, and not in Cloudera Manager.